# How do I make a textbox that only accepts a type of data?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a form and would like to know how to make it accept only one type of date. (Ex: DD/MM/YYYY)

[image]

I tried to find something referring to #c but I only found the logic for numbers and not date formats

Comment: There should be a control such as `DateTimePicker` for that.

Comment: paul9722, What should happen if the user types in a non-date?

Comment: There are a gazillion date formats. Some even look the same but are _very_ differently interpreted. Use the right tool for the right job. If the default DateTimePicker doesn't meet your taste: ok. I can understand that. But you _will_ regret going into text-to-date without narrowing down accepted input to _one specific unambiguous format_.

Comment: You could use an input mask IIRC.... but 01/01/2022 is ambiguous, if you really really want to deal with string dates, better stick with ISO (that's YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 0):

you can use NuGet MaskedTextBox, and call like this:

```
maskedTextBox1.Masked = MaskedTextBox.MaskedTextBox.Mask.DateOnly;
```

Code and example: https://github.com/abbaye/Winform-MaskedTextBox

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `DateTimePicker` in the toolbox.
This tool allows you to only insert types of `DateTime`.
Then in your code you can change it to any format you would like
with the `Tostring` method.
look in this webpage to look into formating of `DateTime`: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1